# Android R cannot be resolved to variable

Tags: android, android-resources

I just had a working app turn into a broken one. When I call any `findViewById`, the app cannot browse R properly and says R cannot be resovled to variable. So none of my drawables and code can be read. It says to import R but then it gets even further into the rabbit hole of fustration.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

edit: I had an error within my strings.xml. IT now works. **Thanks to the helpful comments.**

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? What package is your activity class in? What is the package for your project?

Comment: Have you ever visited Microsoft's support forums? First answer is always the same: "Have you tried turning it off and on again"? Same here, what happens when you clean project? Check your layout files, maybe you added a comment, which breaks xml?

Comment: Im using Eclipse ADT. My package is in com.jakegosskuehn.couchto5k.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probable cause is an error in one of your layouts. If the resource compiler can't compile the resources, it doesn't generate the file defining R, so suddenly R becomes unresolvable.

Look through your layouts for something wrong. It will probably be the change you made just before it all went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should fix any syntax errors in your main layout first.